# How to get text/control values from WebBrowser control?

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I have developed an application, which helps me generating reference letters for students,
(C#, DocX, VS 2010). There are a dozen fields that need to be set (mainly text boxes)
so that I then press generate button to get my word document.

Now these dozen values must be copy/pasted from a web site (I must login there, search
student id, wait for loading of student details, and then I can copy paste values in my App)

Earlier I have a little experience with WebBrowser control, but I was unable to
extract text after logging on to a web page.

Please suggest me what should I do, and if there is another better solution then
WebBrowser control then also indicate.

Comment: You can try watin - http://watin.org/

Comment: It is quite easy with the Winforms version of the WebBrowser control, its Document property is the HtmlDocument class that lets you access the DOM after the DocumentCompleted event fires.  More painful in WPF.  "I was unable" doesn't help us help you.